# How to move a json item one level higher in bash?

Tags: bash, jq

I have a json response object that follows this format:

```
{
 "storagePoolList": [
   {
     "status": Online
     "statusCode": 0,
     "storagePolicyEntity": {
       "_type_": 17,
       "storagePolicyName": "n1",
       "storagePolicyId": 38
      },
     "storagePoolEntity": {
       "storagePoolName": "n2",
       "_type_": 160,
       "storagePoolId": 38
     },
     "storagePool": {
       "_type_": 28,
       "clientGroupId": 38,
       "clientGroupName": "ddsa"
     }
   },
   {
     "status": "Online",
     "statusCode": 0,
     "storagePolicyEntity": {
       "_type_": 17,
       "storagePolicyName": "dsa",
       "storagePolicyId": 65
     },
     "storagePoolEntity": {
       "storagePoolName": "dasdas",
       "_type_": 160,
       "storagePoolId": 65
     },
     "storagePool": {
       "_type_": 28,
       "clientGroupId": 65,
       "clientGroupName": "fasdf"
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

Assume that there's more of these, not only two. The thing is, I want the `storagePolicyName` one level higher, at the same level as `status` item.

The json object is stored in a `data` variable

What I've tried is this:

```
need_this=$(echo "$data" | jq '.storagePoolList |= map(.storagePolicyName = .storagePolicyEntity.storagePolicyName | del(.storagePolicyEntity))')
```

But it doesn't work (output is unchanged), I've been racking my mind for a while now, what I wrote I "tried" is just the latest version of the script that has seen way too many changes.

I come to you asking for help

Comment: Not sure why this got a few downvotes within 10minutes, but keep in mind that `Online` makes your json invalid, it should be quoted: `"Online"`

Comment: @0stone0  Ah, my mistake; the original response has Online in "". I just forgot to add them while writing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the `storagePoolList` array, map each object, assign `storagePoolName` to `.storagePoolEntity.storagePoolName`

```
.storagePoolList |= map(.storagePoolName = .storagePoolEntity.storagePoolName)
```

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Le7g4S1uqdi)

---

If you want to remove the `storagePoolEntitiy.storegePoolName` from the inner object, use `del()`:

```
(.storagePoolList |= map(.storagePoolName = .storagePoolEntity.storagePoolName | del(.storagePolicyEntity.storagePolicyName)))
```

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/U5xXtaysijg)

---